# Google Earth/Maps in different languages

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I am new to Google Earth / Maps and programming in general.

I am working on a project that must display/list the 1st Level Admin Names (States/Province) of each country of the world from Google Earth / Maps.

Is there a file that is accessible that would list the 1st Level Admin Names (States/Province)  in the 43 languages that Google Earth offers?

Obtaining the file of all the 1st Level Admin Names (States/Province) in the different languages would save me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Google doesn't offer the list data of all states/provinces. I think you should find the data as postal code. http://www.geonames.org/postal-codes/

Answer (score 0):

There are two main sets of countries and theis subdivisions. One is the ISO3166 standard and the other is the list provided by United Nations. They are the two most widely used standards worldwide:

**ISO 3166** - International Standard for countries and subdivisions (

base: 
http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes.htm;

txt file with the countries: http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements_txt.htm );

**UN** Multilingual, multiscriptual dataset of names of countries, capitals and major cities ( http://unstats.un.org/unsd/geoinfo/geonames/Default.aspx ).

I'm afraid you will need to pay for the ISO of all countries subdivisions. 
But the UN data you can download for free. They also provide other databases on their websites.